# How to improve search in an array of HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, hash

A search in any HashMap (or any hash based data structure) requires a single hash operation i-e O(1). However, when we have to search through an array of HashMaps then a single search will requires O(n) hash operations, where n is the size of array. I was wondering since array is a collections of consecutive memory locations, therefore there could be an efficient method to reduce the search from O(n) to O(1) in array of HashMap. Or we can design some object that in fact have the advantage of array as well as require single hash operation for search. Any suggestion ???

Consider the scenario, You are processing elements from different users and you want to keep them based on user profiles (separate from each other). The most memory efficient way is to keep them separate is using array of HashMap.

Comment: Why do you have an array of HashMaps in the first place?

Comment: You're taking a really weird and questionable data structure and asking if it's possible to design a better one.  Yes, it is and already has been done.  First stop using the weird and questionable one. :-)

Comment: There could be different reasons. For instance I have to maintain elements in HashMap. For some reasons when the number of elements in a HashMap increases I create another HashMap. I know how many HashMap will be created, so I create an array of HashMap. And at the same time I have to search for some elements, so thats why I need array of HashMap

Comment: `HashMap` expands automatically in size.  No need to create a second one when the number of elements increases.

Comment: @The111 As I said in my previous comment that there could be many reasons for which you required an array of HashMap. Consider the scenario, You are processing elements from different users and you want to keep them based on user profiles (separate from each other). The most memory efficient way is to keep them separate is using array of HashMap.

Comment: No, the most efficient way would be to keep `n` separate hashmaps and one overall hashmap, such that you have one map for each type of query you want to do. The overhead of the extra hashmap is only in the structure, you won't duplicate any user data.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your question to include the hypothetical scenario of various user accounts, each with various properties.  As mentioned in a different answer, the solution here is a map of maps.  There are two separate searches occurring:

1. Find the right user
2. Find the right property of this user

Each of these searches can be done with a separate map.

The user map:

```
class Application {

    ...

    Map<String, User> userMap = new HashMap<>();

    public User getUser(String userName) {
        return userMap.get(userName);
    }

    ...
}
```

The property map:

```
class User {

    ...

    Map<String, Property> propertyMap = new HashMap<>();

    public Property getProperty(String propertyName) {
        return propertyMap .get(propertyName);
    }

    ...
}
```

Now to find the property named `favoriteTowel` of the user named `Arthur Dent`:

```
myApplication.getUser("Arthur Dent").getProperty("favoriteTowel");
```

Comment: Very well. I like the approach. It has reduced the search from O(n) to O(2) at the expense of a little more memory. Since now we are explicitly maintaining the identity of the user. In the array, the index is used as an identity of the user. But I suppose this could be the only answer since in array we can not reduce the search to less than O(n).

Comment: @user3212493 Glad it helped!  Yes, you have the right idea.  True, an array is just a map using counting numbers as keys. :-)  If you know the user ID of each user in advance, and you use only consecutive numbers with no gaps, then sure you can keep using an array as your backing data structure... but it's still a map of maps logically!  Also, O(2) is constant time which is O(1).  Big O complexity describes upper bound, not precise number of steps.

Comment: I did not realized the actual problem. Actually we dont know the name of the user. So we have to search through all the users that have the property.

Comment: Search through all users that have the property... for what?  If you don't know the user name, what **do** you know about him?  How do you know when you get to the right user?

Answer (score 1):

The answer for this is in your question. When you're using an ordinary Array to store these elements, there's no way to get O(1) complexity when searching it.

You stated that the complexity of searching a Hash Map is O(1), so why not store those Hash Maps... in a Hash Map? I'll leave the implementation of that up to you, haha.

Comment: Storing HashMap within HashMap is not going to work. For instance  HashMap<HashMap<String, Integer>,Integer> obj=new HashMap<>(); in obj searching for string is not possible with out a loop that iterate through all the hashmaps

Comment: @user3212493 You need to configure each map with a key that allows you to search it; that's the whole point of maps.  The example you give above of course does not allow smart search of the top map, because you've given it a key that you can't know in advance.  See my answer for a more reasonable implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**Go Go For `java.util` packages, Go Go for Java Collections**

look at set (`Hashset`, `enumset`) and hash (`HashMap`,`linkedhash`...,`idnetityhash`..) based implementations. `they have O(1) for contains()`

Below are stats for reference.

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: I know this package, but it seems to me that non of them can solve my problem as I am talking about array of HashMap. Search in array of HashMap is O(n). Of-course search in a single HashMap is O(1).

Comment: @user3212493 then there is no such standard APi available, time to write your own algo to achieve this.